# If a collection is locally finite, then the collection of all closures is also locally finite

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove the following Lemma. Let $A$ be a locally finite collection of subset of a topological space $X$. Then the collection $B=\{\bar{a}\mid a\in A\}$ of the closure of elements of $A$ is locally finite. I can see that for any $x\in X$, there is an open neighbourhood U which intersects with finitely many $a\in A$'s. However, the closure of $a$ contains the limits points which maybe extra to $a$. So I do not see why the limit points of $a$'s intersection with $U$ must be empty all the time.

Comment: An **open** set $U$, which is disjoint from a set $a$, is also disjoint from the closure of $a$. In other words, since $a$ is contained in the **closed** set $X\setminus U$, $\bar a$ is also contained in that closed set.

Comment: I wasn't able to convince myself that we can choose $U$ intersecting finitely many $a$. Did you do this by construction or contradiction?

Comment: @user20672 Such a $U$ exists by the definition of a locally finite collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $a \in A$ such that $\overline a \cap U \ne \varnothing$. Either $U$ contains a point of $a$ and we are done, or $U$ contains a limit point of $a$, but then $U$ is a neighborhood of a limit point of $a$, so it must contain a point of $a$ itself.