# About the collection of closures of elements of a locally finite family

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove that given a locally finite family of subsets of a topological space $X$, $\mathcal{F}$, then the family $\{ \overline{F} \,|\, F \in \mathcal{F} \}$ is also locally finite. Some definitions: let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space.

> $N \subset X$ is a neighborhood of $x \in X$ iff there exists $O \in \tau$ such that $x \in O \subset N$.

> A family $\mathcal{F} := \{\, F_{\alpha} \subset X \mid \alpha \in A \,\}$ is said to be locally finite iff for all $x \in X$ there exists a neighborhood $N_{x}$ of $x$ such that $N_{x} \cap F_{\alpha} \neq \varnothing$ for finitely many $\alpha \in A$.

I'm trying to prove that

> If $\mathcal{F}$ is a locally finite family, then the family $\overline{\mathcal{F}} := \{\, \overline{F} \mid F \in \mathcal{F} \,\}$, where $\overline{F}$ is the closure of $F$, also is locally finite.

This result is theorem 1.1.13 in Engelking's General Topology and proposition 9.2(1) in Dugundji's Topology. Dugundji provides a proof but he defined neighborhoods to be open neighborhoods, that is, simply an open set. In that case the proof is clear to me. Engelking, on the other hand, works with the same definition of neighborhood as above but doesn't provide a proof.

I'm having trouble proving the result in that case for, if $\mathcal{F}$ is a locally finite family and $N_{x}$ a neighborhood of $x$, then even if $N_{x}$ intercepts only finitely many elements $F \in \mathcal{F}$, $N_{x}$ can, in principle, contain a limit point of each $F \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $N_{x} \cap \overline{F} \neq \varnothing$ for each $F$. If that happens, than $\overline{\mathcal{F}}$ is not locally finite.

I've found some related questions:

- [If a collection is locally finite, then the collection of all closures is also locally finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951823/if-a-collection-is-locally-finite-then-the-collection-of-all-closures-is-also-l)
- [The collection of closures of each set in a locally finite collection of subsets of a topological space is locally finite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338259/the-collection-of-closures-of-each-set-in-a-locally-finite-collection-of-subsets)
- [Collection $\mathcal B=${$\bar A:A\in \mathcal A$} is locally finite,given that $\mathcal A$ is locally finite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051515/collection-mathcal-b-bar-aa-in-mathcal-a-is-locally-finite-given-that)

But in all of them, the neighborhood is taken to be open. If that's the case then I know how to proceed. But I don't understand why I can always take the neighborhood to be open, as the accepted answer in the last question says. So, my question is: why can I take the neighborhood to be open? If I can't, than how can I prove this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ that intersects finitely-many elements of a collection. Choose an open set $U$ with $x\in U\subset N$. Then $U$ is an open neighborhood that intersects finitely-many elements of that collection.

Comment: Oh! Of course... Thank you!